# List all Timers in EAR with multiple EJB modules

Tags: java, timer, scheduler, ear, ejb-3.1

I need get all Timers of my EAR project, but if I use:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ScheduleManagment {

@Resource
private TimerService tsvc;
public List<ScheduledTimerInfo> getAllTimers() {
    return tsvc.getAllTimers()
            .stream()
            .map((timer)  -> new ScheduledTimerInfo(timer))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
}
```

Only get the timers of this EJB container, and I need get all timers of my EAR project multimodule. Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Java API states that only Timers on the same module will be listed from getAllTimers().

[Interface TimerService - method getAllTimers()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html#getAllTimers--)

> Returns all active timers associated with the beans **in the same
>   module in which the caller bean is packaged**. These include both the
>   programmatically-created timers and the automatically-created timers.

---

Maybe you should consider building a kind of REST interface for each module.
I've recently found a site with some ideas in that perspective. Please have a look at:

[RESTful timers in Java EE / Posted on July 13, 2015](https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/restful-timers-in-java-ee/)